# Revert auth state to last anonymous

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have a website where authentication isn't mandatory to be able to use the website.

To be able to persist user data even when not signed in, I'm using `signInAnonymously()` in my `AppComponent`.

When the user wants to register to the website, I'm following these steps:

- Ask for oauth.
- Check if this oauth is already in my database.

  - If the oauth is not already in the db, revert to the last anonymous state.
  - If it's already in the db, get user data.

But here is the issue: once I called `signInWithPopup()`, the last auth state is lost and because it's an anonymous one, I can't sign in to it again.

Because the anonymous state contains data I don't want the user to loose, I have to be able to revert to the last anonymous state if the registration process fails.

Comment: It is not clear when you say " if this oauth is already in my database". are you planning to upgrade the anonymous user to an OAuth user on some condition and if the condition is not met, stick to the anonymous user?

Comment: exactly, when a user goes to the registration page and registers, I add his email and another data into the database. The login process goal is to check if the email is present in the db, and if it is, login successful, else login failed and go back to the last anonymous state.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand your use case but anyway here goes.
You sign the user anonymously on the default App instance.

```
var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
app.auth().signInAnonymously()....
```

You then create another Auth instance with same config:

```
var appTemp = firebase.initializeApp(config, 'temp');
// Set persistence to none in case you forget to clear this.
appTemp.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);
// Sign in the user with popup and save the credential.
var cred = null;
appTemp.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  cred = result.credential;
  // Check the user email is registered in your DB.
  return isRegistered(result.user.email);
}).then(function(registered) {
  if (registered) {
    // User is registered. Delete and relink to original anonymous.
    return appTemp.auth().currentUser.delete().then(function() {
       return app.auth().currentUser.linkWithCredential(cred);
    });
  } else {
    // User not registered, just delete. The anonymous user remains.
    return appTemp.auth().currentUser.delete();
  }
})...
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but it will point you in the right direction using the temp auth instance copy technique.